# What is the difference between each and any to find a prime number in Ruby

Tags: ruby

There are two completely identical methods, only one uses **each** and the other **any**, so what is the difference between **each** and **any**?

*first program code (**each** using):*

```
def is_prime?(num)
   Math.sqrt(num).floor.downto(2).each {|i| return false if num % i == 0}
   true
end
number = gets.chomp.to_i;
puts is_prime?(number);
```

*second program code (**any** using):*

```
def is_prime?(num)
   Math.sqrt(num).floor.downto(2).any? {|i| return false if num % i == 0}
   true
end
number = gets.chomp.to_i;
puts is_prime?(number);
```

Comment: each just gives you an iterator that allows you to loop through the elements. any? also gives an iterator but returns true if any of the block iterations is truthy. They are not designed to be the same thing but how you use them here - they do the same thing.

Comment: What @JoelBlum said additionally you could use the inverse of `any?` ( which is `none?`) and avoid the early return (`return false`) and the hanging return (`true`). e.g. `Math.sqrt(num).floor.downto(2).none? {|i| num % i == 0}`

Comment: `Math.sqrt(num).floor` much faster and more reliable is `Integer.sqrt(num)`.

Answer (score 1):

`each` is the iterator that go through the array from beginning to end

Its main purpose is just to pass through the array (or other collection) and perform some actions that were specified in the block. For example, it can be a rendering of HTML partial or making HTTP requests or something else

There are also many other iterators that have specific tasks. These are such as `map`, `select`, `any?` and others

You used it wrong way. You're not using the full power of a specific iterator

But you can do it like this:

```
def prime?(num)
  !Math.sqrt(num).floor.downto(2).any? { |i| num % i == 0 }
end
```

or like this

```
def prime?(num)
  Math.sqrt(num).floor.downto(2).all? { |i| num % i != 0 }
end
```

Comment: I don't think these two prime? functions are equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

The [`.each` method](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.5/Array.html#method-i-each) iterates through all elements of a data structure, most commonly an array or a hash, and calls the given block once for each element. If no block is given, it returns an enumerator, i.e. an instance of the Enumerator class that can then be used to "manually" iterate through the data structure.

The [`.any?` method](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.5/Enumerable.html#method-i-any-3F) tests every element of a data structure against the given condition and returns `true` if one or more of them match or pass the test. Otherwise, it returns `false`. There are more details to it, so please check it from the official documentation.

### General tips using Ruby

Based on this code, there are a couple of suggestions. First, you should not use `return` in a block as it makes the method return that value, too, and might not execute the block for more iterations.

Second, you don't need trailing semicolons at the ends of lines.

### Short analysis of your code

Both your functions seem to work, at least for some numbers, but it seems that you might not exactly know why. Let's take a closer look at it.

Let's assume `num = 5`, for example.

First function, the block variable `i` gets assigned to a value of 2, meaning the block does not use the `return false` because the test `num % i == 0` fails. Instead, the function returns `true` from the next line.

Second function, the block variable `i` also gets assigned to a value of 2, but again, as the test `num % i == 0` fails the result of `.any?` is `false`, and the function returns `true` from the next line.

Now, let's assume `num = 4`.

First function, the block variable `i` gets again assigned to a value of 2, and since this time the test `num % i == 0` passes, the `return false` inside the block is executed making the function return `false`.

Second function, the block variable `i` also gets again assigned to a value of 2, and since the test `num % i == 0` passes here as well, the `return false` inside the block is executed making the function return `false`.

Without the `return false` in your second function, the function would always return `true` because you would not check the value returned by `.any?`, and the function's next line would be executed returning `true`.

Mechnicov offers simpler alternatives how to make your function more understandable.

Comment: Just a comment `any?` short circuits on the first truthy (not `nil` or `false`) value. It will only test every value in 2 instances 1) the last evaluation is truthy; 2) none of the evaluations are truthy